# Deciphering My Cipher: Python Wizardry

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function `decipher(s)` that takes an enciphered string where the characters have been rotated, and returns the original English string. An example:

```
>>> decipher('Bzdrzq bhogdq? H oqdedq Bzdrzq rzkzc.')
'Caesar ciaapher? I preferr Caesaar saladd.'
```

It should only take a string as an input. Here are all of the functions I have written to encipher. I'm wondering how can I use my `rot` function to score all possible options in `letter_prob` and then return a string with all of the `max` (most probable) letter occurrences.

```
def decipher(s):
    lc= [rot for c in s] 
    options = [lc for n in range(26)]
    scored_options = [[letter_prob(c),c] for c in options]
    best_option = max(scored_options)
    return best_option[1]
```

How do I rewrite `decipher` so that it returns one string containing all of the most probable characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but something like this should work:

```
def decipher(s):
    options = [[rot(c, n) for c in s] for n in range(26)]
    best_option = max(options, key=lambda x: sum(map(letter_prob, x)))
    return ''.join(best_option)
```

`options` will be a list of every combination, like this:

```
[['B', 'z', 'd', 'r', 'z', 'q', ...], ['C', 'a', 'e', 's', 'a', 'r', ...], ...]
```

Then we use [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) with the `key` argument to get the option with the highest sum of letter probabilities. `''.join()` converts the list of characters back into a string.

---

```
def decipher(s):
    options = [[rot(c, n) for c in s] for n in range(26)]
    scored_options = [[sum(map(letter_prob, x)), x] for x in options]
    best_option = max(options)
    return ''.join(best_option)
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a vectorized version of your code using NumPy.  I find this a bit more clear (though if you haven't seen NumPy before it will be a bit foreign at first), and it will be much faster for long strings:

```
import numpy as np

_a = ord('a')
_z = ord('z')
_A = ord('A')
_Z = ord('Z')

def encipher(s, n):
    arr = np.fromstring(s, np.uint8)
    rawcipher(arr, n)
    return arr.tostring()

def rawcipher(arr, n):
    lower = (arr >= _a) & (arr <= _z)
    upper = (arr >= _A) & (arr <= _Z)
    arr[lower | upper] += n
    arr[lower & (arr > _z)] -= 26
    arr[upper & (arr > _Z)] -= 26

letters = np.ones(128, dtype=np.float32)
letters[ord(' ')] = 0.1904
letters[ord('e')] = 0.1017
letters[ord('t')] = 0.0737
letters[ord('a')] = 0.0661
letters[ord('o')] = 0.0610
letters[ord('i')] = 0.0562
letters[ord('n')] = 0.0557
letters[ord('h')] = 0.0542
letters[ord('s')] = 0.0508
letters[ord('r')] = 0.0458
letters[ord('d')] = 0.0369
letters[ord('l')] = 0.0325
letters[ord('u')] = 0.0228
letters[ord('m')] = 0.0205
letters[ord('c')] = 0.0192
letters[ord('w')] = 0.0190
letters[ord('f')] = 0.0175
letters[ord('y')] = 0.0165
letters[ord('g')] = 0.0161
letters[ord('p')] = 0.0131
letters[ord('b')] = 0.0115
letters[ord('v')] = 0.0088
letters[ord('k')] = 0.0066
letters[ord('x')] = 0.0014
letters[ord('j')] = 0.0008
letters[ord('q')] = 0.0008
letters[ord('z')] = 0.0005
letters[_A:_Z+1] = letters[_a:_z+1]

def score(arr):
    return letters[arr].sum()

def decipher(s):
    arr = np.fromstring(s, np.uint8)
    bestStr = None
    bestScore = 0
    for n in range(0, 26):
        rawcipher(arr, 1)
        thisScore = score(arr)
        if thisScore > bestScore:
            bestScore = thisScore
            bestStr = arr.tostring()

    return bestStr
```

Note that the only loop in Python here is from 0-26 when attempting all possible decipher distances.

I timed it, and my vectorized encipher() takes 3.6 seconds to process 122 MB, whereas the original version takes forever (I gave up after 40 minutes).